How to categorize timestamps into time groups based on intervals in BigQuery?
I need to assign a time_group to each logged_time based on the following logic:

For the earliest timestamp, the time_group should be the same as logged_time.
For subsequent rows, compare the logged_time to the previous row's time_group:

If the difference between logged_time and time_group is within 3 minutes, use the previous row's time_group.
If the difference exceeds 3 minutes, set the time_group to the current logged_time.






logged_time
time_group (expected)




2023-12-10 17:03:05
2023-12-10 17:03:05


2023-12-10 17:05:02
2023-12-10 17:03:05


2023-12-10 17:06:18
2023-12-10 17:06:18


2023-12-10 17:10:07
2023-12-10 17:10:07


2023-12-11 08:31:27
2023-12-11 08:31:27



I’ve been trying to implement this in BigQuery, but I can’t seem to achieve the desired output.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You can achieve the desired behavior in BigQuery by using window functions along with some logic in CASE and LAST_VALUE. Below is a step-by-step solution to correctly assign the time_group based on your specified rules.
WITH grouped_data AS (
SELECT
    logged_time,
    -- Calculate the time difference in seconds from the previous row
    TIMESTAMP_DIFF(logged_time, LAG(logged_time) OVER (ORDER BY logged_time), SECOND) AS diff_seconds,
    -- Determine if a new group should start
    CASE 
      WHEN LAG(logged_time) OVER (ORDER BY logged_time) IS NULL OR 
           TIMESTAMP_DIFF(logged_time, LAG(logged_time) OVER (ORDER BY logged_time), SECOND) > 180 
      THEN logged_time
      ELSE NULL
    END AS new_group_marker
  FROM your_table_name
),
final_grouping AS (
  SELECT
    logged_time,
    -- Propagate the new group marker forward
    LAST_VALUE(new_group_marker IGNORE NULLS) OVER (
      ORDER BY logged_time ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
    ) AS time_group
  FROM grouped_data
)
SELECT
  logged_time,
  time_group
FROM final_grouping
ORDER BY logged_time;

Time difference:
LAG(logged_time) retrieves the logged_time of the previous row.
TIMESTAMP_DIFF calculates the difference in seconds between the current row and the previous one.
New group marker:
A CASE statement is used to define when a new group should start:
For the first row (LAG(logged_time) IS NULL).
When the time difference exceeds 3 minutes (180 seconds).
Group propagation:
LAST_VALUE with IGNORE NULLS propagates the most recent non-NULL new_group_marker forward, assigning it as the time_group for all rows within the same group.
Sorting and displaying results:
Finally, select and order the logged_time and time_group columns.
I hope this helps!
